# Unknown word/character in txt file from word2vec

Tags: python, word2vec

I recently encountered the `</s>` word/character in a vocabulary created by word2vec as a separate word.

Although I did tried to search the web for that character, I cannot actually specify that character at the search engines.

So, does anyone knows what this character is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the line 82 of [source code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/source/default/source) of `word2vec`,

```
if (ch == '\n') {
  strcpy(word, (char *)"</s>");
  return;
}
```

`</s>` is simply a character used by Mikolov et al. to denote the end of line (or more precisely `\n`). 
I don't think it has any special html/latex reference. Nor does it appears on ASCII [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters).

Comment: It's probably just used to avoid collision with words in the text you are training `word2vec` on.